# How to send tokens to contract address

Tags: ethereum, solidity, truffle

I want to send erc20 tokens to contract address which is able to trade the token.

However, I failed the test and error says 
`Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert`

My function is this

TokenSale.sol

```
  function startSale(address _tokenSaleContractAddress) public {
    require(msg.sender == admin);
    require(tokenContract.transfer(_tokenSaleContractAddress, 750000)); 
  }
```

MyToken.sol

```
  function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
    require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value);

    balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;
    balanceOf[_to] += _value;

    emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);

    return true;
  }
```

My test is this

```
  it('facilitates start sale', function() {
    return MyToken.deployed().then(function(instance) {
      tokenInstance = instance;
      return TokenSale.deployed()
    }).then(function(instance) {
      tokenSaleInstance = instance;
      return tokenSaleInstance.startSale(tokenSaleInstance.address, {from: admin} )
    }).then(function(receipt) {

      return tokenInstance.balanceOf(tokenSaleInstance.address)
    }).then(function(balance) {
      assert.equal(balance.toNumber, 750000);
    });
  });
```

Could you give me any advise why I failed the test?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the rest of your code, but it doesn't look like you're transferring any tokens to the `TokenSale` contract, so when it tries to transfer tokens, it has an insufficient balance. Also, it looks like you're trying to have the `TokenSale` contract transfer tokens to itself? You're calling `startSale` and passing in the `TokenSale`'s own address as a parameter.

Comment: Admin has 1000000 tokens, and I want to send 750000 tokens to `TokenSale` contract.

Comment: I posted my code in github. https://github.com/Yosuke-Aramaki/erc20_proto_react.git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Admin has 1000000 tokens, and I want to send 750000 tokens to `TokenSale` contract.

To do this, the *admin* needs to call `transfer` on the token contract. I.e. your test code should have this in it:

```
tokenInstance.transfer(tokenSaleInstance.address, 750000, { from: admin });
```

After that, calling `startSale` should succeed, but there's no reason to call it because it's just transferring 750,000 tokens to itself.